# Python: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available

Tags: python, ssl, anaconda, mod-wsgi, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to connect to Stripe to setup payments. I have it working on my dev machine, but when I push to prod, I get the following SSL error:

**Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.**

Here are the details of my setup:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Apache 2
- mod_wsgi
- Python 3.6
- Django 1.11
- Python/django processes are all installed and running in an anaconda (miniconda) virtual environment called "protectyourreviews"

I've read multiple other SO answers that suggest reinstalling python, but to be sure to install dependencies first. That shouldn't be an issue when installing inside and anaconda environment should it? Shouldn't anaconda take care of all of the dependencies for me?

I have HTTPS enabled and working for the entire domain (all requests are routed to https). When I check my install, I do have openssl, and when I open a shell in my django environment, I can import and use the module without issue... so I'm not sure how to continue troubleshooting the issue.

Any help is much appreciated!

---

*Also, heres a stack trace:*

```
File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/protectyourreviews/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py" in urlopen
  589.             conn = self._get_conn(timeout=pool_timeout)

File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/protectyourreviews/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py" in _get_conn
  251.         return conn or self._new_conn()

File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/protectyourreviews/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py" in _new_conn
  827.             raise SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL "

During handling of the above exception (Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.), another exception occurred:

File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/protectyourreviews/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py" in send
  440.                     timeout=timeout

File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/protectyourreviews/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py" in urlopen
  639.                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])

File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/protectyourreviews/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py" in increment
  388.             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))

During handling of the above exception (HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.stripe.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/customers (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",))), another exception occurred:

File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/protectyourreviews/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stripe/http_client.py" in request
  121.                                                **kwargs)

File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/protectyourreviews/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py" in request
  508.         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/protectyourreviews/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py" in send
  618.         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)

File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/protectyourreviews/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py" in send
  506.                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)

During handling of the above exception (HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.stripe.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/customers (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",))), another exception occurred:

File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/protectyourreviews/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/protectyourreviews/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/protectyourreviews/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/protectyourreviews/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/protectyourreviews/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/user/protectyourreviews/protectyourreviews/../payments/views.py" in stripe_test
  35.                 source=token

File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/protectyourreviews/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stripe/resource.py" in create
  467.         response, api_key = requestor.request('post', url, params, headers)

File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/protectyourreviews/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py" in request
  150.             method.lower(), url, params, headers)

File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/protectyourreviews/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py" in request_raw
  335.             method, abs_url, headers, post_data)

File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/protectyourreviews/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stripe/http_client.py" in request
  139.             self._handle_request_error(e)

File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/protectyourreviews/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stripe/http_client.py" in _handle_request_error
  159.         raise error.APIConnectionError(msg)

Exception Type: APIConnectionError at /payments/test/stripe/
Exception Value: Unexpected error communicating with Stripe.  If this problem persists,
let us know at support@stripe.com.

(Network error: SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.stripe.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/customers (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)))
```

---

**Edit**

---

After re-instaling mod_wsgi in a fresh python virtualenv, it's still trying to open the old anaconda path. I've changed the python-home and python-path directives in WSGIDaemonProcess, but no matter what I try, it's still trying to open python from the miniconda3 directory (which I've deleted).

Here's a trace from Apache error logs:

```
Current thread 0x00007f99f6769780 (most recent call first):
[Mon Aug 28 20:13:15.264466 2017] [core:notice] [pid 26528] AH00051: child pid 26775 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Mon Aug 28 20:13:15.264608 2017] [core:notice] [pid 26528] AH00051: child pid 26776 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Mon Aug 28 20:13:16.340556 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 26789] mod_wsgi (pid=26789): Python home /home/user/miniconda3/envs/protectyourreviews.
[Mon Aug 28 20:13:16.341203 2017] [wsgi:warn] [pid 26789] (2)No such file or directory: mod_wsgi (pid=26789): Unable to stat Python home /home/user/miniconda3/envs/protectyourreviews. Python interpreter may not be a$
[Mon Aug 28 20:13:16.341357 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 26789] mod_wsgi (pid=26789): Initializing Python.
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
```

---

**Edit 2**

---

Yes, I did start from a clean source directory. I copied the mod_wsgi tar file to the new directory and ran configure/make/make install in the new directory. I believe I also deleted the apache module files before the new install just in case.

I've tried multiple iterations of the below directives (both / only python-home / only python-path) but no matter what I try, I can't figure out why mod_wsgi keeps looking in the deleted miniconda3 folder. Is there some other config file that I'm forgetting about?

Here's my wsgi.load:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

Here are my Apache2 directives (where pyr_env is my new Python virtualenv folder):

```
WSGIDaemonProcess protectyourreviews python-home=/home/user/pyr_env/ python-path=/home/user/protectyourreviews
WSGIProcessGroup protectyourreviews

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/protectyourreviews/zz_test/test.wsgi
<Directory /home/user/protectyourreviews/zz_test>
        <Files test.wsgi>
                Require all granted
        </Files>
</Directory>
```

---

**Edit 3**

---

I followed the instructions you suggested [in the docs](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-shared-library), and the output follows.

Here's the output of ldd:

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffad973000)
        libpython3.5m.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0 (0x00007f05b8c02000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f05b89e5000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f05b861a000)
        libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f05b83f1000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f05b81d7000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f05b7fd2000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f05b7dcf000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f05b7ac6000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000558bed982000)
```

And here's the output after unsetting LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
$ unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$ ldd /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd91bd2000)
        libpython3.5m.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0 (0x00007f8bec8a6000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f8bec689000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8bec2be000)
        libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f8bec095000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f8bebe7b000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f8bebc76000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f8beba73000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8beb76a000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055e8861a5000)
```

---

### **Edit 4**

I made sure permissions are set correctly on the virtual environment folder, and also recompiled again to be absolutely sure I have the correct version. Here's all input and output from the process:

```
#----CHANGE PERMISSIONS OF VIRTUAL ENVIRONMENT
$ sudo chgrp -R www-data /home/user/pyr_env/
$ sudo chmod -R g+rwx /home/user/pyr_env/

#----DELETE OLD FOLDER
$ rm -r mod_wsgi-4.5.17/

#----START FRESH WITH CONFIG/MAKE/INSTALL
$ tar xvfz 4.5.17.tar.gz
$ cd mod_wsgi-4.5.17/
$ ./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python3
$ make
$ sudo make install
    /usr/bin/apxs2 -i -S LIBEXECDIR=/usr/lib/apache2/modules -n 'mod_wsgi' src/server/mod_wsgi.la
    /usr/share/apache2/build/instdso.sh SH_LIBTOOL='/usr/share/apr-1.0/build/libtool' src/server/mod_wsgi.la /usr/lib/apache2/modules
    /usr/share/apr-1.0/build/libtool --mode=install install src/server/mod_wsgi.la /usr/lib/apache2/modules/
    libtool: install: install src/server/.libs/mod_wsgi.so /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
    libtool: install: install src/server/.libs/mod_wsgi.lai /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.la
    libtool: finish: PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/sbin" ldconfig -n /usr/lib/apache2/modules
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Libraries have been installed in:
       /usr/lib/apache2/modules

    If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
    in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
    specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
    flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
       - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
         during execution
       - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
         during linking
       - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
       - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

    See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
    more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    chmod 644 /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so

#----OUTPUT OF LDD
$ ldd /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcfb9a9000)
        libpython3.5m.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0 (0x00007f19ae26f000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f19ae052000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f19adc87000)
        libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f19ada5e000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f19ad844000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f19ad63f000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f19ad43c000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f19ad133000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055aa1cb7a000)

#----RESTART APACHE
$ sudo apache2ctl restart
```

Unfortunately I'm seeing the exact same errors in Apache. Here's *apache2/error.log*:

```
Current thread 0x00007fb350fee780 (most recent call first):
[Wed Aug 30 14:13:08.130076 2017] [core:notice] [pid 9754] AH00051: child pid 28636 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Wed Aug 30 14:13:08.130179 2017] [core:error] [pid 9754] AH00546: no record of generation 0 of exiting child 28636
[Wed Aug 30 14:13:08.130833 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28639] mod_wsgi (pid=28639): Python home /home/user/miniconda3/envs/protectyourreviews.
[Wed Aug 30 14:13:08.130907 2017] [wsgi:warn] [pid 28639] (2)No such file or directory: mod_wsgi (pid=28639): Unable to stat Python home /home/user/minico$
[Wed Aug 30 14:13:08.130992 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28639] mod_wsgi (pid=28639): Initializing Python.
[Wed Aug 30 14:13:08.131665 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28638] mod_wsgi (pid=28638): Python home /home/user/miniconda3/envs/protectyourreviews.
[Wed Aug 30 14:13:08.131716 2017] [wsgi:warn] [pid 28638] (2)No such file or directory: mod_wsgi (pid=28638): Unable to stat Python home /home/user/minico$
[Wed Aug 30 14:13:08.131782 2017] [wsgi:info] [pid 28638] mod_wsgi (pid=28638): Initializing Python.
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
```

It's still trying to open the *miniconda* folder that was deleted...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that Anaconda Python ships with its own SSL libraries and does not use the system SSL libraries when compiling the Python ssl module. The mod_ssl module in Apache is using the system libraries.

So if you enable mod_ssl in Apache, it pulls in the system SSL libraries. When the Python ssl module is imported by your application, it inherits the already loaded system SSL libraries, which are different to what the ssl module was compiled for and expects, thus it fails.

So the issue is caused by Anaconda Python ignoring the system SSL libraries and using its own.

The only solution is to use the system Python version and not Anaconda Python, or run your WSGI application using mod_wsgi-express behind your main Apache installation which would only act as termination point for SSL and then proxy to the mod_wsgi-express instance.

Unless you have a specific requirement, is better to use the system Python version and not Anaconda Python.

Comment: Thanks so much Graham! I realized from your answer that I had probably compiled mod_wsgi against the wrong python. I started fresh with a new python virtualenv (no anaconda) and reinstalled mod_wsgi. I followed all directions [here](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html) to start in daemon mode, but no matter what I do with the _python-home_ or _python-path_, it's still looking in the old anaconda directory (which I deleted).  Any ideas on what I'm missing? Or would it be better if I open a new question for this one?

Comment: I added another trace to my question above @Graham Dumpleton

Comment: Did you start from fresh mod_wsgi source code directory, or at least run ``make distclean`` in mod_wsgi source directory if used the same so old compiled files were removed. I presume you are using the configure/make/make install method. Also, what directives have you added along with ``LoadModule`` to load the mod_wsgi module.

Comment: Again, thanks for the help Graham! :)  Yes I did start from scratch with configure/make/make install in a fresh directory, but no luck yet. I added more info on my directives in the question above.

Comment: What do you get when you run ``ldd /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so``? See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-shared-library

Comment: I included the output of ldd in the question above. I ran it inside of my virtual environment... hopefully that was the right thing to do. (See Edit 3)

Comment: So mod_wsgi is compiled against Python 3.5. Is the virtual environment definitely created against the system Python 3.5 installation? Also double check that you don't have another ``LoadModule`` line for ``wsgi_module`` in the Apache configuration files anywhere. Also because the virtual environment is in a user directory, what are the permissions on the users home directory. Ie., run ``ls -lasd /home/user``. Often home directories are not readable to others, meaning that the Apache user cannot see into the user home directory.

Comment: Thanks Graham! I may have compiled mod_wsgi while inside of the virtual environment (they're both python 3.5). I'll recompile to make sure that isn't the issue. As long as I compile while in the system shell, that's what I need right?

Comment: Am more concerned about permissions on file system at this point. Can you also edit the question with the most up to date errors based on this latest mod_wsgi module build and Apache configuration.

Comment: Hey Graham, I changed permissions and also recompiled as per your suggestion. All input/output of that process is included in the question above, as well as current error output. (See Edit 4) I'm seeing the same error. Apache directives haven't been changed (since Edit 2).

Comment: I've scoured wsgi.load / wsgi.conf / (apache).conf files and there's no mention of miniconda3 in any file. Any idea why I can't point wsgi to any other folder? I have over 100 hours of work on this server, and I would love to save it if possible! ;-)

Comment: Search everywhere you can under Apache configuration files, both in available and enabled directories for everything, in case a symlink got replace by a copy of a file with old settings, for any WSGI directives and specifically ``WSGIPythonHome``. In the ``wsgi.load`` file, add at end ``WSGIRestrictEmbedded On`` to ensure embedded mode is disabled. Ensure that ``PYTHONHOME`` environment variable is not set somehow in Apache startup scripts.

Comment: You were right Graham! There was a rogue `WSGIPythonHome` directive that I found by running `grep -R -i "python"` on my apache2 folder. Thank you so much for all your help!!!