# Sending mail works in manage.py shell, but not in running app

Tags: python, django, email, mod-wsgi

I'm attempting to send an email to the site admins using `django.core.mail.mail_admins` (Django 1.11) when a comment is submitted via a view. I have a method on my `Comment` model called `send_notification_email`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.mail import mail_admins

class Comment(models.Model):
    comment = models.TextField()
    time_received = models.DateTimeField()

    def send_notification_email(self):
        mail_admins(
            f'New Comment (id = {self.id})',
            f'Comment {self.id}, received at {self.time_received}: {self.comment}',
        )
```

The view creates an instance of `Comment`, saves it to the database, then calls `send_notification_email()`. When that happens, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/conda/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 52, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/radio-website/main/views.py", line 56, in comments
    )
  File "/home/radio-website/main/models.py", line 33, in send_notification_email
    [settings.SERVER_EMAIL],
  File "/home/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 56, in send_mail
    fail_silently=fail_silently,
  File "/home/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 36, in get_connection
    klass = import_string(backend or settings.EMAIL_BACKEND)
  File "/home/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/home/conda/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 4, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "/home/conda/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 101, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: /home/conda/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: SSL_get0_alpn_selected
```

Python is installed using Conda. The server is hosted via Apache 2.4 with `mod_wsgi`, running in daemon mode.

Running similar code in `manage.py shell` works as expected. For example,

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> from main.models import Comment
>>> c = Comment(id = 0, comment = 'foo')
>>> c.send_notification_email()
```

successfully sends an email to the admin users. I've checked that doing it "manually" works as root and as the `www-data` user that Apache runs the app as. `import ssl` and `import _ssl` both work when run from a normal Python interpreter session or the `manage.py shell`.

I find it very odd that this would work in the shell but not when the app is actually running. The error seems quite weird and obscure - perhaps something is wrong with my Python installation?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45908938/python-cant-connect-to-https-url-because-the-ssl-module-is-not-available Or same reason at least.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Worked like a charm once I cleaned out the references to the conda install (just like in the linked question). Thanks!