# Python Https Query with Requests and Installed SSL Certificate - Error SSL Module Not Available

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, certificate, ssl-certificate

Requests can't connect to HTTPS URL because SSL module is not available.

I have a certificate installed from a vendor, and I am attempting to download an XML file from that vendor via Requests. I can access the XML file through Chrome, but when I attempt to reach the XML via Requests in Python, I get the error urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.

I am using Python 3, and I have installed it in C:\Users\Name\Python folder. I am unable to figure out what is causing this error, and any help would be immensely appreciated. I have the feeling that it is because my Python installation does not see or reach the certificates store when running, but I can't figure out how to fix this if it is in fact the case.

The URL used is not the actual URL, but I am unable to provide the used one. I can go to that same URL I am attempting to use in the actual code via chrome and download the file.

As for the verify=False, I have tried with and without this code.

```
def Earlybird(daycount):

    url = 'https://smd.xyz.com/rest/day=20190101
    response = requests.get(url, verify=False)
    print(response)

Earlybird(0)
```

Comment: You should do some research first or let us now why your exact error message is pointing to e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45908938/python-cant-connect-to-https-url-because-the-ssl-module-is-not-available while that answer doesn't help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45908938/python-cant-connect-to-https-url-because-the-ssl-module-is-not-available)