# cannot access URL due to SSL module not available Python

Tags: python, api, ssl, python-requests

First time trying to use Python 3.6 requests library's get() function with data from quandl.com and load and dump json.

```
import json
import requests


request = requests.get("https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/CHRIS/MX_CGZ2.json?api_key=api_keyxxxxx", verify=False)
request_text=request.text()


data = json.loads(request_text)

data_serialized = json.dumps(data)

print(data_serialized)
```

I have an account at quandl.com to access the data. The error when python program is run in cmd line says "cannot connect to HTTPS URL because SSL mode not available."

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/45908938/463213

Comment: with python 3.7 work OK

Comment: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings()

r = requests.get(
    "https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/CHRIS/MX_CGZ2.json?api_key=api_keyxxxxx").json()

print(r)
```

Output will be the following since i don't have `API` `Key`

```
{'quandl_error': {'code': 'QEAx01', 'message': 'We could not recognize your API key. Please check your API key and try again.'}}
```

> You don't need to import `json` module as `requests` already have it.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have verified 'quandl_api_keys received the following error when trying to retrieve data with 'print' data 'json.dumps' function: "quandl_error": {"code": "QEAx01" ...  discovered that the incorrect fonts on the quotation marks around key code in the .env file resulted in this error. Check language settings and fonts before making requests after the error mssg.